# Google Play Services Admob Migration - InjectView.value must be a constant

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

I'm in the process of doing a Google Play Services Migration for admobs, unfortunately I seem to have hit a wall while implementing the Google Play Services library into my project.

Im getting this error with my existing code that was working fine, but it doesn't seem to like the Google Play Services library..

**Error** - ''**The value for annotation attribute InjectView.value must be a constant expression** '' -

@Inject
private DataSource mDataSource;

@InjectView(R.id.progress)
private TextView mProgressTextView;

@InjectView(R.id.fragmentContainer)
private ViewGroup mFragmentContainer;

@InjectView(R.id.messages)
private View mSoundWarning;

@InjectView(R.id.score)
private TextView mScoreTextView;

Thanks, hope you can help

Comment: Doing this removed the errors, I've no idea how or why. @InjectView(tag="progress");

Comment: Nope it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Library projects do not use constant identifiers in their R files. This makes it impossible to use library project ids in @InjectView annotations, because annotations require constants values.

Instead, use view tags to identify your views.

@InjectView(tag="foobar") TextView foobarView;
And in your layout: